# Select and de select not working properly while click on the parent node?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, treeview, nodes

I have a problem to Select and Deselect the all nodes using parent node. When i select and deselect the Parent node("Select All") slowly, its working fine. but When i select and Deselect the Parent node("Select All") fastly, it will not working fine to other nodes.
i have attached the simple sample to select and deselect all the nodes in the tree view. Please refer the below image and suggest me any solution to avoid this problem?

[image]How to Select and Deselect the all the nodes using Parent node? > node clcik.png

Sample: [WindowsFormsApplication.zip](https://syncfusion.atlassian.net/wiki/download/attachments/116884525/WindowsFormsApplication.zip?version=1&modificationDate=1467376260346&api=v2)

Regards, Venkat.

Comment: You can use JQuery to do this easily

Comment: ok. but i have to do in C#. if you have suggest in C# , please suggest me

Comment: Try this:

Create checkbox as:
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" runat="server" />

Comment: And JQuery as: $(function () { $('#chkSelectAll').click(function () { if (this.checked) { $("input[name='checkAll']").each(function () { this.checked = true; }); } else { $("input[name='checkAll']").each(function () { this.checked = false; }); } }); });